# Hibernate C3P0 "Apparent DeadLocks"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

In my server production suddenly I got an **"Apparent Deadlock"** error after which the production stopped working, the error logs is provided below:-

```
[2019.11.20 16:38:13,090] WARNING [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner ] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@ce1a019 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!  
[2019.11.20 16:38:13,102] WARNING [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner ] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@ce1a019 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 15
    Active Threads: 15
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@4bcf8f73
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#7
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@27d2ede7
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#12
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@900ed1e
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#10
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@1bcf5130
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#11
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@47db3493
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#3
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@858c3c0
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#6
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@7b9b7687
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#1
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@1b82d877
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#9
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@2b517abd
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#4
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@72512482
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#13
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@2d340d70
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#0
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@345e4b3f
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#14
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@1a9e2ff5
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#5
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@75e8b7a
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#8
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@5016fa5d
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#2
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@148f18bf
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@3ea1ae24
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@68afdd9b
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@71fe20ce
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@631beed9
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@3ede1b64
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@67d8627a
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@2f296cd9
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@48a932bf
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@5c42bedd
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@2200ce7d
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@62f481fb
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@2281b87e
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@727769e4
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@7dc93271
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@240ed93b
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#12,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#7,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#10,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#11,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#3,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#6,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#1,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#9,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#4,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#13,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#0,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#14,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#5,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#8,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->c7i4u9uoib6bylsor9|2ecf995]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:575)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

After restarting the server, it started working fine but now I am getting frequent **Deadlock Error** -

```
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,436] WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions] SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,437] ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions] Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,437] INFO [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release] HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,441] WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions] SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,442] ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions] Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,442] INFO [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release] HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,443] WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions] SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,443] ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions] Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,444] INFO [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release] HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,444] WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions] SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,445] ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions] Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction  
[2019.11.20 17:08:33,445] INFO [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release] HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is given below:-

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">200</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">90</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">64</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">15</property>
```

Anyone could tell me what could be the cause or how to prevent this Deadlock issue.

> I checked previously the c3p0 properties configuration documentation and found some clues to alter the hibernate.c3p0 properties as shown below. Please let me know if i am on right path or if I am missing or doing something wrong.

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">64</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin ">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.privilegeSpawnedThreads">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.contextClassLoaderSource">library</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">15</property>
```

> Some information on Apparent Deadlock and the cause/flow of this issue would be appreciated